# I need assistance in determing what is wrong with my delete statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I keep getting a:

> Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax:

My delete statement looks like this:

```
"DELETE FROM tblSymbol WHERE UserID=$PersonID"."AND Symbol=$stock"
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with my delete statement? Am I using it right?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there does not seem to be space before `AND`.

Second, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should not use $ variables to construct your statements. Instead, use `?` instead and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 1):

In

```
"DELETE FROM tblSymbol WHERE UserID=$PersonID"."AND Symbol=$stock"
```

When you concatenate it, it will look like this:

```
DELETE FROM tblSymbol WHERE UserID=$PersonIDAND Symbol=$stock
```

Notice there is no space before AND.

Also, make sure that the $variables are being replaced correctly, because SQL will expect the correct datatypes (numbers, or strings enclosed in quotes, or...)

Comment: thanks guys. That got rid of that error, but now Im getting a Fatal error: Unknown column 'MCD' in 'where clause'. what would be causing that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = 'DELETE * FROM tblSymbol WHERE UserID='.$PersonID.' AND Symbol='.$stock;
```

Or, alternatively

```
$query = 'DELETE * FROM tblSymbol WHERE UserID=$PersonID AND Symbol=$stock';
```

**EDIT**:
Notice that I've added the `*` symbol, meaning "delete everything that matches the criteria"

Comment: thanks guys. That got rid of that error, but now Im getting a Fatal error: Unknown column 'MCD' in 'where clause'. what would be causing that?

Comment: You did not specify what you want to delete, see my edit

Comment: Have you tried my edit?